# Preventing users from sharing their login credentials using auth0.com

Tags: auth0, credentials, subscription

How can I prevent users from sharing their login credentials and misusing my subscription-based application with auth0.com? Are there any restrictions or controls I can implement to prevent multiple logins with the same account from different devices or IPs using the auth0.com platform?